# Type mismatch gives different WHERE results

Tags: mysql

I had a bug in my code. Instead for a string `'137226000008073943'`, I was looking for a big integer in `varchar(20) utf8_general_ci` column:

`SELECT job_id FROM job WHERE invoice = 137226000008073943`

Could someone please explain why I got two results - one with the same number, another with `137226000008073929`?

I will need to go through the records to find another potential wrong matches so your hint may tell me what to focus on. Thanks!

Comment: i have tested it with MariaDB and get the same error. I have open a ticket by MariaDB to get a answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer from MariaDB:

I guess the problem is described here
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/type-conversion/#rules-for-conversion-on-comparison and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html

please use CAST to avoid the problem (select * from t1 where vc =  CAST(137226000008073943 AS CHAR); )

Comment: Thanks! While this is helpful, my question wasn't really about preventing the bug from happening (I used %d in my PHP/sprintf where I should just use '%s' and now I fixed it), but an explanation why just the two matched so I could possibly check where I could have other possible error results.